# Single Nav Bar for UISplitView

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uisplitview

I would like to have a single navigation bar that sits across both my master and detail views. How can I do this?

When I initially set up the SplitView, I end up with separate nav headers like in the iOS Settings App. I would like a single nav bar across both master and detail views (on an iPad). This nav bar should show up on the phone too over the views (and have a "go back" arrow on the detail view for the phone).

I would like it to look like this (mocked up in Photoshop).

[image: SplitView]

How can I make this work? Do I need to somehow remove the nav bar from the default UISplitView and embed the whole thing in a super-navbar controller?

This has to sit in a tab view. I notice that Apple's Music app does this. In Music, on the My Music tab, there is a split view and at the top there is a single Nav bar. How did they do this?